# importing point attributes from a txt file

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am currently trying to add labels (attributes, names, labels, whatever you may call it) to points that i added via the vector layer -> import txt as layer.

So I imported a WCS-layer and wrote a txt file that contains tab separated data:
[image]

QGIS (Nodebo) did put points on the map, however i would like to know how to get QGIS to use the 'NAME' column to label the respective points.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite straight forward. I have provided you with some screenshots on how to do the labelling. I used your sample data.

[image: The sample data]

Steps:
1. Add the layer as a delimited text layer. Details in pictures 2 and 3.
When you have displayed the data as points.

2. Right click on the data in the layers panel. Click on the labels tab, select "show labels for this layer". then set the label field to attribute. This is also highlighted in the screenshots.

[image: Add a delimited text layer]

[image: Create a layer from a delimited text layer]

[image: Edit label]

[image: Final Output]

Answer (score 1):

Right click the layer in your table of contents, Properties, then go to the layers tab.

On the Labels tab select "Show labels for this layer" from the top drop down then select the field you want to use as your label field in the second drop down (in this case "ATTRIBUTE".  As you get more advanced you can use the expression builder to create more complex labels.

Below the sample field there are several tabs that let you format your labels, size, font, orientation, etc.

Comment: Also is not mandatory but you can export the file to shape file, sometimes if you have many points is better